# Why does a hot bulb filament emit photons?

Tags: optics, photon-emission

Heating up a bulb filament provides energy to the filament material thus exciting the electrons. So how does excitation of electrons release photons generating   light since excitation of an electron leads to absorption of a photon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do electric currents make light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355214/)

Comment: This question was worded with unnecessarily convoluted language. I simplified it a bit, but it's still confusing. Can you try to clear up the second sentence? Please keep in mind that clear language is much better than eloquent language when communicating on technical issues.

Comment: Please also readout our [FAQ on question titles](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: @DanielSank  sounds like use of  "google translate" , so one cannot evaluate the language used really. If people's english is not up to par, they cannot judge.

Comment: You have thought of the process  of an electron excitation , which absorbs energy in the form of virtual photons from the current passing through the bulb,  but not about the deexcitation, i.e. the electrons falling to lower energy states and emitting photons. All types of energy states, from atomic to molecular to solid state lattice.